# Why does the leaflet example from R4DS not work?

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm reading the book "R for data science" (R4DS) and there is a example about leaflet but the code does not work.

here is the code from the book:

```
library(leaflet)

leaflet%>%
  setView(174.764,-36.877,zoom = 16)%>%
  addTiles()%>%
  addMarkers(174.764,-36.877,popup = "Maungawhau")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in dispatch(map, "setView", leaflet = { : Invalid map parameter
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: This runs for me without error. Tested with `leaflet_2.0.2` and `R 3.6.0`. Did you try this new in a session? Do you have anything suspicious listed when you run `conflicts()`

Comment: Try using brackets `()` after the `leaflet` statement. Works for me.